# Is it possible to change the month label in primefaces calendar navigator dropdown list

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible to change the month label in PrimeFaces calendar navigator dropdown list to make it full and not abbreviated as by default.

[image]

Instead of Sep, show Septembre?

Comment: Hi, please start by reading the PrimeFaces documentation about calendar https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales (hint: shortNames can be converted to also contain the long ones)

Comment: @Kukeltje yes I know that, but the width of the month drop down list is not suitable for this long labels

Comment: Ok but can you not change that with CSS? (and next time please state things you tried, saves me searching ;-))

Comment: So, basically your question is wrong. Are you looking to change the values or the width of the select? The latter makes it a completely different question.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: I think both are needed. The css part due to the names getting longer

Comment: @Nouali Yahya, if my answer resolved your problem, don't forget to [accept it as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the short names values in a locale-primefaces.js file (e.g.: see Janeiro below):

```
PrimeFaces.locales['pt_BR'] = {
    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['veryLongJaneiroNameInHere', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S'],
    closeText: 'Fechar',
    prevText: 'Anterior',
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    currentText: 'Hoje',
    weekHeader: 'Semana',
    firstDay: 0,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    timeOnlyTitle: 'Só Horas',
    timeText: 'Tempo',
    hourText: 'Hora',
    minuteText: 'Minuto',
    secondText: 'Segundo',
    ampm: false,
    month: 'Mês',
    week: 'Semana',
    day: 'Dia',
    allDayText: 'Todo o Dia'
};
```

Then use it in the component:

```
<p:calendar locale="pt_BR" navigator="true" .../>
```

[image: see the result]

Regards,

To adjust the drop down size when closed, use it in your css file:

```
.ui-datepicker-month {
size: 500px !important;
top: 500px !important;
width: 200px !important;
}
```

Result:

[image: month label adjusted]

You can do it to you year label, too.

Comment: Please read the additional comments below the question... The long names do not seem to fit if this is the only thing being done. Please enhance your answer.

Comment: I've read. But in his image there is not a long name and the op asked to show long names in it. This component has an auto fit feature, just test it. See it in my updated answer too.

Comment: And what do you see when The Drop down is closed

Comment: Well, that was not th op question, should be done in another new. But just to eliminate the doubts, see my (again) updated answer explaining how you can adjust the size of the closed dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Let your locale is en_US.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
PrimeFaces.locales ['en_US'].monthNamesShort = PrimeFaces.locales ['en_US'].monthNames
</script>
```